# colander schema data type define for password input filed?

Tags: python, jinja2, pyramid, deform, colander

I create login form(email and password field) schema using deform and colander  .
but password filed show my password character.
how to hide as normal HTML password input filed.

```py
email =  colander.SchemaNode(
    colander.Str(),
    title='Email',
    validator=colander.All(colander.Email()),
    widget=deform.widget.TextInputWidget(size=40, maxlength=260, type='email',  placeholder="youremail@example.com"),
    description="The email address under which you have your account.")
password = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only created a schema node without a PasswordWidget. See the [deform demo example](http://demo.substanced.net/deformdemo/password/):

```
password = colander.SchemaNode(
    colander.String(),
    validator=colander.Length(min=5, max=100),
    widget=deform.widget.PasswordWidget(),
    description='Enter a password')
```

Comment: How to validate a input field accept only string value(no number and spcl character)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not ask a second question in a comment. Create a new question. Also if I answered your original question satisfactorily, then please accept it as the correct answer. If you need guidance for how StackOverflow works, then see the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for an overview.